# Need edit profile link in the menu for logged in users wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a page called edit profile, i have installed the profile builder plugin,so the users can edit their profile from front end, if the user is logged in i wants to show the edit profile and logout links in the menu else it is login. how can i achieve that? i am using wp-bootstrap responsive theme, i am new in wordpress development any one please help me.Do i need to change any thing in the header.php file?

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    // i want to add Edit profile and logout to the menu
} else {
    // i want to add login to the menu
} ?>
```

Comment: What wordpress version are you using?

Comment: 3.7.1 and the the theme is wp-bootsstrap

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `wp_nav_menu_items` filter  to add the menu

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_items', 'your_custom_menu_item', 10, 2 );
function your_custom_menu_item ( $items, $args ) {

if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    $items .= '<a href="user profile link">Show whatever</a>';
} else {
     $items .= '<a href="login link">Show whatever</a>';
}

    return $items; /* This will have the menu items */
}
```

[**Reference**](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-themes/how-to-add-custom-items-to-specific-wordpress-menus/)

Comment: Do i want to add new menu for this? i am using wp-bootssrtap plugin

Comment: i guess you don't need to add new menu ,i assume wp-bootssrtap plugin has implemented the wordpress menu so it will work

Comment: Css not coming for this menu

Comment: @Naveen No idea for that buddy but i guess you need to add the classes for your anchor link